# How to limit MySQL query results to top 3

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get this database query to return only the 3 most common states, but somehow I keep getting all the states returned, listed in descending order. Not sure where I am going wrong...?

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) as count
FROM Contact
GROUP BY state
HAVING state NOT IN(' ')
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: query looks good, could you provide some sample data if possible on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Looks like your query actually works fine ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc57/2

Comment: @user1218172 Your query works fine. Why this not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're using `HAVING` correctly.

I would simply use this query

```
SELECT state, COUNT(1) AS state_count
FROM Contact
WHERE state <> ' '
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state_count DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Demo ~ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc57/1

Comment: @user1218172 I'm not entirely sure why your original query wasn't working. Looks ok in the demo I linked